# Show UIAlertView on splash screen

Tags: iphone, uialertview, splash-screen

I used to show a splash screen which in background load some data from web, I also check that if the location of the user is changed from one city to another city I want to show in alert to the user with the message that you are now in "CityName" would you like to see data from this city?

I have tabbed application and I have presented the splash screen as follow in the app delegate class.

```
SplashViewController *controller = [[SplashViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
tabBarController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
controller.tabBarController = self.tabBarController;
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
[window addSubview:controller.view ];
//[window addSubview:tabBarController.view ];

[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
[controller release];
```

Now when I show the alert screen it crash the application with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" message and the stack trace show that _buttonClick is released in UIAlertView class.

Please advise what should I do, I also tried with UIActionSheet but the same problem with this thing too.

I think there is some problem with the model thing with the current view (SplashView).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does my strategy is wrong? I should not identify the user's location and fetch data from web on splash screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue, the problem was that my Splash View was a modeled view and invoked by

[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

what I did that I shifted the data downloading to another view controller and there I can show alerts, and can handle that

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to display your UIAlertView inside of your SplashViewController viewDidAppear? If not, I would try that first. I would also make sure you have your UIAlertView clickedButtonAtIndex method setup properly to try and trap what is going on.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
    initWithTitle:@"Your Location Has Changed" 
    message:@"Your location has changed since you last opened opened THEAPP. Would you like to refresh your data?" delegate:self 
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
    otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
alert.tag = 1;
[alert show];
[alert autorelease];
```

Then for the clickedButtonAtIndex method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    //--NSLog(@"You clicked button #%i",buttonIndex);

    if (alertView.tag == 1){

        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            //--NSLog(@"CANCEL");

        } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            //--NSLog(@"OK");

        }
    }
}
```

Doing all of this on a splash screen should be fine as long as you take into account the HIG's requirements for using the users location. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am still getting the error !! the only diffrence I was doing was to release the alert  and you are doing it as autorelease .... To reproduce I think you have to open a view by presentModalViewController and then show alert in that opened view the same problem will occure